# Dimension of the intersection of subspaces when interchanging the complement.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that if $U \subseteq V$, $M \subseteq V$ are vector subspaces with $Dim(U) = Dim(M)$ then

$$dim(U \cap M^{\perp}) = dim(U^\perp \cap M)$$

When trying to prove this i feel like i am missing some key identity explaining how complements and intersections interact. Can someone help me get started on this?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean that $\dim(U)=\dim(M)$?

Comment: Of course, sorry, it is corrected now.

Comment: Hint: Just use the following, for any two subspaces $A,B,$ we have $\text{dim}(A\cap B)+\text{dim}(A^\perp \cap B)=\text{dim}(B)$